# MySQL select query in where clause where two conditions need to be met

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

This problem seemed quite simple when I decided to tackle it, but it's proving to be very difficult. It involves displaying a 'range' of details based on what the visitor selects from a dropdown list.

The dropdown list contains options like V01 N01, V01 N02. V=Volume, N=Number. Each volume has 20 numbers within it and there are 50 volumes. So the Search dropdown list will contain V01 N01-V01 N20, V02 N01-V02 N20 and so on upto V50 N20.

If the visitor want to display all books between V08 N10 and V12 N23, I would like to display all the books FROM V08 N10 right upto V12 N23. My code strips the selection down so that MySQL will receive VolumeNo = 8 and IssueNo = 10.

However, I cannot think of a SELECT statement that does what I want it to do. Here it is (brevity version):

> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (VolumeNo >= 8 and IssueNo >= 10) and (VolumeNo <= 12 and IssueNo <= 23)

This obviously doesn't work, but I hope you get the gist of what I am trying to accomplish here. I'd appreciate any guidance offered. Thank you.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: (-1 really?) 
It appears that my original question wasn't clear enough. Even though my 'desired result' was the 'gist' code supplied.

The DDLs are large so here's a DDL description:
V01 N01
V01 N02
V01 N03
   |      |
V01 N20
V02 N01
V02 N02
   |      |
V02 N20
V03 N01
all the way through to V50 N20.

So if the visitor wants to display all books from V08 N10 to V50 N20 the display of books should be:

V08 N10, V08 N11 thru to V08 N20, 
V09 N01, V09 N02 thru to V09 N20,
thru to V50 N20 

The 'OR' suggestion doesn't work, because books like V01 N01 and many other unrequired books get displayed.

Comment: I believe that you could provide a representative data set in as few as 8 rows

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR` instead of `And` to work for both the conditions

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (VolumeNo >= 8 and IssueNo >= 10) OR (VolumeNo <= 12 and IssueNo <= 23)
```